# Access Display Message Box if Query Conditions Met

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi I'm trying to display a Message Box based on values from a query. I've tried the DLookUp function of the following:

```
If (DLookup("ID1", "qry_CheckID") = Forms!MainForm!ID2) Then
    MsgBox "Your ID is bad.", vbOKOnly, ""
End If
```

Basically I want to see if ID1 from my query matches with ID2 in my form. However the DLookUp isn't working as (I had) intended.

Comment: You didn't specify 'criteria' for the DLookup, thus a random value is returned - unless your query limits the data somehow.

Comment: I also tried the following: 
  

  If (DLookup("ID1", "qry_CheckID", "ID1" = Forms!MainForm!ID2)=Forms!MainForm!ID2) Then
    MsgBox "Your ID is bad.", vbOKOnly, ""
    End If


. I was unsuccessful with that. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Add a debug.print before your 'IF' and display the parts of your test. I like 'Debug.Print ">" & DLookup(....) & "<"  and similar for your TextBox. What values do you get? Since I can't see your query or data or results... hard to guess.

Comment: Please add more information:  If it's not working as intended, what is it doing instead?  If you open the query qry_CheckID, what is returned?  What value is returned from the statement DLookup("ID1", "qry_CheckID")?

Comment: My query is for people that meet certain criteria to mark them as 'Bad' ID's. I want to have a button (on a separate customer form) that when clicked, will check to see if the customer's ID (from the opened form) matched any ID listed in my query. If there  are ID's that match from the open form with any ID in the query, then I want a message that says "This customer is marked bad." Otherwise, if there are no matching IDs, then nothing will happen. 

Clicking the button it doesn't result in anything. I receive no error messages and no changes in anything. No message box appears.

Comment: Like I said earlier - without criteria in the DLookup, a random record will be returned. If random is good enough, then run the code until you get a hit :)  If you prefer to see if that Customer ID is 'bad', either change your query to filter on that specific Customer ID (plus whatever else you do in there), or tell us the results of the debug.print(s) after several runs.

Answer (score 1):

Include filter criteria in the DLookup. Concatenate variables, reference to the form field/control is a variable. If there is no match, Null will return. Since in your comment you said you want the message only if there is a match in the query:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("ID1", "qry_CheckID", "ID1 = " & Forms!MainForm!ID2)) Then
MsgBox "Your ID is bad.", vbOKOnly, ""
End If
```